# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Promise<any[]>' with | async

Tags: asynchronous, typescript, promise, angular

### "Property 'push' does not exist on thype 'IHero[] | Promise'. Property does not exist on type 'Promise'[image]

Why the heck not? isn't it an array?

[image]

Going through the Tour of Heroes with Angular 4 in an angular-cli project. I'm using the async pipe for the repeater instead of the official tutorial's method.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

[image]

heroes.component.ts

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: IHero[]|Promise<IHero[]> = [];
    selectedHero: IHero;

    constructor(private _heroService: HeroService, private _router: Router)

    ngOnInit() {
        this.heroes = this._heroService.getHeroes();
    }

    add(name: string): void {
        name = name.trim();
        if (!name) { return; } 
        this._heroService.create(name)
            .then(hero => {
                this.heroes.push(hero); // RED SQUIGGLY ERROR HERE "Property 'push' does not exist on thype 'IHero[] | Promise<IHero[]>'. Property does not exist on type 'Promise<IHero[]>'"
            });
    }
}
```

hero.service.ts

```
...
getHeroes(): Promise<IHero[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then( res => res.json().data as IHero[] )
        .catch( this._handleError) 
}
...
```

If I console.log out the this.heroes on init, I can see it is a ZoneAwarePromise....

[image]

#### How can I get the .push to work on this?

If I use a traditional .then method, then the | async pipe errors. out.

[image]

Wall of Errors ensues...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = this._heroService.getHeroes();
}
```

should be

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._heroService.getHeroes().then(val => this.heroes = val);
}
```

With your code you assign a `Promise` which doesn't have a `push` method.

Comment: Sorry, I want to use the async pipe. Therefore no .then's. That's the whole point, as I understand, of the | async --- so we can assign get calls to variables directly without the .then or .subscribe.

Comment: If there is no array, you can't use `push()`.  I don't know a good suggestion. You might be able to use an observable that emits values from different sources but that would require more knowledge about your use case. I don't even know where to start with questions :D

Comment: So it seems I have to extract the array from the Promise somehow... The goal is to use the | async pipe....

Comment: What you want to do (modify received value) doesn't seem to be compatible with `| async`.

Comment: So does mean that an array of values (with all array methods like push, pop, shift, and unshift) that is typed Promise<any[]> cannot be extracted?

Comment: Sure, by calling `.then(...)` ;-) or by using `| async` pipe, but then you can't modify it.

Comment: Ok.. if I use .then, then I cannot use the | async pipe.. Wall of red errors.

Comment: There is no need to use the `| async` pipe if you use the code from my answer.

Comment: But my whole point is to use | async. That's the point of my question. Cheers.

Comment: So I can use | async.

Comment: As I wrote before, you can either use `|async` but then you can't modify the value, or you can do what I posted in my answer, then you can't use async, and I don't get why you would *need* to use `| async` when it's not required.

Comment: You can continue to use async ( for instance to trigger change detection if using onpush). But the previous commenters are correct, you cannot "push" onto the promise. What you need to do is add a new method to your service to handle the add, something like addHero(hero). In that method, you can push the new hero onto the array that underlies the promise.